# Jooq Update statement on POJO failing

Tags: jooq

On using update statement for a POJO in JOOQ I am getting
error: 'column "public" of relation "tableName" does not exist'.
Is there some configuration I am missing for the update statement to work ?

```
Class MyBook extends com.generated.tables.pojo.Book {

}

com.generated.tables.dao.BookDao.update(MyBook);
```

It fails with the above mentioned error.
Database: POSTGRES

Comment: How did you generate the classes? What is MyBook ?

Comment: I used gradle plugin etiennestuder: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin
to generate pojos and daos. MyBook is a custom Pojo which extends the generated Pojo.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. Can you please update your question with an example showing what you're doing *exactly*, and which allows for reproducing the problem you're seeing? There's a template you could use to better show what you were doing: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve